# Why do I get this "invalid 'times' argument" error when using left_join() in R?

Tags: r

I have two tibbles, and I can't figure out why I'm getting an error when I use `left_join` to merge them:

```
df <- structure(list(animal = c("cat", "dog", "mouse", "rat", 
"pidgeon", "fish"), value = c(-2.71, -2.63, 
-2.66, -6.99, -2.11, -6.44), ID = c("2700", 
NA, NA, "4821", "55117", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> df
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  animal  value ID   
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
1 cat     -2.71 2700 
2 dog     -2.63 NA   
3 mouse   -2.66 NA   
4 rat     -6.99 4821 
5 pidgeon -2.11 55117

new_vals <- structure(list(animal = c("dog", "pidgeon"), ID_new = c("123456", "25255")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

> new_vals
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  animal  ID_new
  <chr>   <chr> 
1 dog     123456
2 pidgeon 25255 


df_new <- left_join(
        df,
        new_vals,
        by = "animal"
    )

Error in rep(x_loc, lengths(y_loc)) : invalid 'times' argument
```

Please could someone tell me where the error is? I feel like I'm going crazy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `df` is somehow corrupted.

If you look at the `structure(.)` output you've provided, you'll see that `"animal"` is length 6, but the structure thinks with `row.names = c(NA, -5L)` that there are only five rows. When you look at `df`, it indeed only has 5 rows *displayed*, but there is still `"fish"` to display.

Fix it programmatically with:

```r
attr(df, "row.names") <- seq_along(df$animal)
df
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   animal  value ID   
# * <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
# 1 cat     -2.71 2700 
# 2 dog     -2.63 <NA> 
# 3 mouse   -2.66 <NA> 
# 4 rat     -6.99 4821 
# 5 pidgeon -2.11 55117
# 6 fish    -6.44 NA
```

Now showing six rows, and the join now works.

```r
left_join(df, new_vals, by = "animal")
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   animal  value ID    ID_new
#   <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
# 1 cat     -2.71 2700  <NA>  
# 2 dog     -2.63 <NA>  123456
# 3 mouse   -2.66 <NA>  <NA>  
# 4 rat     -6.99 4821  <NA>  
# 5 pidgeon -2.11 55117 25255 
# 6 fish    -6.44 NA    <NA>
```

(I don't know how this would have happened ... if you read that in programmatically elsewhere, you should review what code was doing what, and either stop doing something you did or report a bug ... that should never happen.)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, upon printing the last row is not included in the dataset from some corruption.  An option is to re-tibble it after `unclass`ing

```
left_join(as_tibble(unclass(df)), new_vals, by = 'animal')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  animal  value ID    ID_new
#  <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
#1 cat     -2.71 2700  <NA>  
#2 dog     -2.63 <NA>  123456
#3 mouse   -2.66 <NA>  <NA>  
#4 rat     -6.99 4821  <NA>  
#5 pidgeon -2.11 55117 25255 
#6 fish    -6.44 NA    <NA>
```

---

This could happen if some transformations change the attribute

```
df1 <- as_tibble(unclass(df))
df1
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  animal  value ID   
#  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
#1 cat     -2.71 2700 
#2 dog     -2.63 <NA> 
#3 mouse   -2.66 <NA> 
#4 rat     -6.99 4821 
#5 pidgeon -2.11 55117
#6 fish    -6.44 NA
```

Now, we can modify the `attributes` as this is a `list` and `list` elements can have different `length`

```
attributes(df1)$row.names <- 1:5
```

However, we cannot do

```
row.names(df1) <- 1:5
```

Now we got the corrupted dataset

```
df1
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  animal  value ID   
#* <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
#1 cat     -2.71 2700 
#2 dog     -2.63 <NA> 
#3 mouse   -2.66 <NA> 
#4 rat     -6.99 4821 
#5 pidgeon -2.11 55117
```

`unclass` removes the `data.frame` attribute and returns a `list` with the `row.names` attribute as well.  Now, we can find the difference in `length` of each `list` element and the `length` of `row.names`

```
unclass(df1)
#$animal
#[1] "cat"     "dog"     "mouse"   "rat"     "pidgeon" "fish"   

#$value
#[1] -2.71 -2.63 -2.66 -6.99 -2.11 -6.44

#$ID
#[1] "2700"  NA      NA      "4821"  "55117" "NA"   

#attr(,"row.names")
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```